# npm-generated command not calling node

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to create a node.js command line utility and having an issue with wrapper that npm generates. My super-simple demo is a package.json file:

```js
{
    "name": "demo-cli",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "bin": { "demo": "bin/demo-cli.js" }
}
```

And the demo-cli.js file:

```js
console.log('DEMO WORKED');
```

The issue is when I install the module using `npm install -g` while in the project directory the wrapper it generates does not call node with the file as the parameter. This is the generated contents of demo.cmd:

```
:: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
"%~dp0\.\node_modules\demo-cli\bin\demo-cli.js"   %*
```

The unix version has the same issue. Looking at another globally installed CLI I can see that node is being tested for and called as expected.

```
:: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\.\node_modules\mocha\bin\mocha" %*
) ELSE (
  node  "%~dp0\.\node_modules\mocha\bin\mocha" %*
)
```

What is the secret sauce needed for npm to generate the proper script file? I've tried everything I could find or think of, including removing the .js extension, preferring global, specifying the node version...no luck.

I'm using node v0.6.18 and npm v1.1.21 on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try putting

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

At the top of your `demo-cli.js` file.

On windows, `npm` looks for this shebang line when creating the `.cmd` wrapper.  See [cmd-shim.js](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/blob/master/lib/utils/cmd-shim.js) in the `npm` source for more info.

Comment: That did the trick. I figured it was something simple missing. Thank you!