# How to get npm package to have working scripts in .bin when installed?

Tags: node.js, command-line, npm

I'm writing a nodejs commandline tool. When I test by running `npm install` and trying to run it locally, npm creates the following files in node_modules/.bin:

---

`node_modules/.bin/myapp` containing:

```
"$basedir/../myapp/dist/myappcli.js"   "$@"
exit $?
```

---

`node_modules/.bin/myapp.cmd` containing:

```
"%~dp0\..\myapp\dist\myappcli.js"   %*
```

---

They aren't very useful.

On the other hand, when I install popular nodejs cli tools, such as js-yaml or typings, I get much more useful files:

---

`node_modules/.bin/typings` containing:

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=`dirname "$0"`

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/../typings/dist/bin.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/../typings/dist/bin.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $re
```

---

`node_modules/.bin/typings.cmd` containing:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\..\typings\dist\bin.js" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\..\typings\dist\bin.js" %*
)
```

---

These actually successfully run their apps. Why do they get this fancy stuff? How can I make my app provide this? Do I have to manually add files into a tgz before uploading it to an npm host? I hope not, because I want to be able to install my app straight from github, or at least have npm pack generate the final, complete tgz.

Thanks

Comment: did you know about 'bin' property that you can define on package.json or are you wondering about how you can have 'tab' auto completion of commands for your cli?

Comment: I have defined the bin property, but it doesn't get me these elaborate scripts. Not concerned about tab completion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line to the very top of the javascript file which serves as the entrypoint for your command line application:

`#!/usr/bin/env node`

Thank you to [jmir for this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10907491/970673).